# Pass v-model from parent to children, and from children to parent

Tags: vuejs2

I have a e-editor component which helds the real editor, then I load the e-editor component in a different component.

My question now is: How can I access the v-model=“content” of the component from the view component, and can I pass data from the view component to the model ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Look at [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).

Comment: You cannot do that with vuejs... Well that's not entirely true, but greatly discourage. However, you can $emit() an event when your data change in your child component, and on the parent, listen to this event. That's one way is your application is small. You can also, like @Vucko said, use Vuex to share data between your components, if your app get quite big enough.